# Not able to save data in Android sharedPreferences using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, auth0

I'm trying to configure the sharedPreferences to store a user access token. I was following this tutorial: https://auth0.com/blog/authenticating-android-apps-developed-with-kotlin/#Securing-Kotlin-App-with-Auth0

Here is my code:

MainActivity.kt

```
    private fun login() {
        val account = Auth0(getString(R.string.com_auth0_client_id), getString(R.string.auth0_domain))
        account.isOIDCConformant = true
        account.isLoggingEnabled = true

        WebAuthProvider.login(account)
            .withScheme(getString(R.string.scheme))
            .withAudience(getString(R.string.audience))
            .start(this@MainActivity, AuthenticationHandler(this@MainActivity))
    }
```

AuthenticationHandler.kt

```
    override fun onSuccess(credentials: Credentials) {
        runOnUiThread {
            Runnable {
                CredentialsManager.saveCredentials(context, credentials)
                val intent = Intent(this@AuthenticationHandler, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

CredentialsManager.kt (it is an object/Singleton)

```
    fun saveCredentials(context: Context, credentials: Credentials) {
        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        sp!!.edit().putString(ACCESS_TOKEN, credentials.accessToken)
            .apply()
    }

    fun getAccessToken(context: Context): String? {
        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        return sp!!.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, null)
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated! When I try to retrieve the access token from sharedPreferences or make a post http request with it all I get is null pointer exception.

I am retrieving it like this: (and I get null)

```
println(CredentialsManager.getAccessToken(this@MainActivity))
```

Comment: How are you determining that it's not saving. What you showed should work, but maybe you are not retrieving it correctly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 im doing 

        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        return sp!!.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, null)
im doing print(sp!!.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, null))

Comment: The code looks fine. Check to make sure the `saveCredentials` function is actually getting called. You can log something inside that function or use the debugging tools.

Comment: If you need help with the crash, post the stacktrace too, please. Anyway, looks like you're treating your `AuthenticationHandler´ as a `Context` when instantiating an `Intent`but you're also instantiating `AuthenticationHandler` yourself so it won't work as a `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

@Lucy Hao
Please check what value is being written, print it, and check it might be null.